# Definition: rational prime, rational integer

Tags: number-theory, definition, rational-numbers

**Context:** In the first 4 pages of Neukirch's text algebraic number theory, there are references to 'rational primes' and 'rational integers'. These come up in the context of finding all primes and units in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

What does this refer to?

**A guess:** A rational prime in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, which is also an element of $\Bbb Q$, rather than being, say, $1+i$ (which is prime, but not a rational number). 'Rational integer' is less clear to me though, since all integers are rational.

**Question:** What do the terms 'rational integer' and 'rational prime' actually mean.

Comment: Algebraic integers (of which there are a surfeit in Neukirch's book) are not necessarily rational.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I haven't (explicitly(?)) mentioned algebraic integers?

Comment: You wrote down $1+i$, which is an algebraic integer.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown as an example of a prime element in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ that isn't in $\Bbb Q$ (meaning what I assume is the sort of thing the term 'a rational prime' excludes intentionally).

Comment: It is not true to say "all integers are rational" - it turns out to be useful to have a notion of "integer" in a wider context. Using the designation "rational integer" implies that you are in a context in which other integers may exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually "rational integer" and "rational prime" is terminology thrown around in algebraic number theory to mean integer of $\mathbb{Q}$ and prime of (the ring of integers of) $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ or primes in $\mathbb{Z}$. This terminology is used to differentiate between the term algebraic integer, which will often be said without the algebraic preceding it, and the term prime which might refer to a prime ideal in the ring of integers of a number field.